# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input ? en js

Tags: javascript, java, fetch, frontend

Tengo este error a la hora de consumir una API en el frontend, la API esta hecha en Java.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque no me deja pintarlo en consola, pero como pueden ver, la respuesta es correcta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El código de JS es este

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    showResponse();
});

async function showResponse() {
    try {
        const url = "http://localhost:8080/HolaMundoServlets/apijava";
        const result = await fetch(url, {
            mode: "no-cors"
        });
        const db = await result.json();
        console.log(db);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Mi código de servidor es este (funciona bien al intenar acceder a la url directamente, aquí no hay problema):

```
package web;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import domain.Employee;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import service.EmployeeService;

@WebServlet("/apijava")
public class JSONTest extends HttpServlet{
    
    private final EmployeeService service = new EmployeeService();
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees = service.getEmployees();
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String employeeJSON = gson.toJson(employees);
        
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        printWriter.write(employeeJSON);
        printWriter.close();
        
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano. <3

Comment: Imprime `result` a ver qué obtienes. Debe haber algún problema con el json.

Comment: Me sale esto: Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
[[Prototype]]: Response

Comment: ¿Si le quitas el `console.log(db);` te sigue pasando?

Comment: Sí, me sigue pasando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione, me falto configurar el acceso CORS en el servidor.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
   version="4.0">
    <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value> http://127.0.0.1:5500, http://localhost:3000 </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
</web-app>
```

Y agregar headers para la respuesta:

```
@WebServlet("/apijava")
public class JSONTest extends HttpServlet{
    
    private final EmployeeService service = new EmployeeService();
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:5500"); // Servidor FrontEnd
        
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees = service.getEmployees();
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String employeeJSON = gson.toJson(employees);
        
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        printWriter.write(employeeJSON);
        printWriter.close();
        
    }
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    showResponse();
});

async function showResponse() {
    try {
        const url = "http://localhost:8080/HolaMundoServlets/apijava";
        const result = await fetch(url);
        const db = await result.json();
        console.log(db);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.